# JavaFX TreeView - Listener if the same TreeCell is in two TreeViews

Tags: javafx, treeview

Is there any possibility to add a listener that changes the graphic of a treecell in treeview1 if that treecell exists in treeview2? And if it gets removed, also removes the graphic ?

A simplified MCVE of my code now, with a button that adds a treeItem from one treeView to another:

```
        Button button2 = new Button("qq");
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    TreeItem<String> treeRoot = new TreeItem<String>("Root Node");
    treeRoot.setExpanded(true);
    treeRoot.getChildren().addAll(
            new TreeItem<String>("Item 1"),
            new TreeItem<String>("Item 2"),
            new TreeItem<String>("Item 3")
    );
    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(treeRoot);

    TreeItem<String> treeRoot2 = new TreeItem<String>("Root Node2");
    treeRoot2.setExpanded(true);
    treeRoot2.getChildren().addAll(
            new TreeItem<String>("Item 1"),
            new TreeItem<String>("Item 2"),
            new TreeItem<String>("Item 3")
    );
    TreeView<String> treeView2 = new TreeView<String>(treeRoot2);

    button2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            treeRoot.getChildren().add(treeRoot2.getChildren().get(1));
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane();
    splitPane.getItems().addAll(treeView, treeView2);
    root.getChildren().addAll(splitPane);
    root.getChildren().add(button2);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: The same `TreeCell` cannot possibly be in two `TreeView`s. If you are asking about a `TreeItem` appearing in two different data models for two `TreeView`s, then you probably shouldn't do that (what are you expecting the result of calling `getParent()` to give on the tree item?).

Comment: Hmm, okay. The reason is because I actually want the treeitem to be in both treeviews. So you are instead suggesting that I remove it from treeview1 when I add it to treeview2? The reason I have this is because a treeitem represents a column in a tableview, and a treview represents the tableview. If the user adds the treeitem to another treeview, I add the column representing it to that table. So with other words, it's actually a visual representation of columns and tables, and columns can be in multiple tables. The user drags columns(treeitems) from other tables(treeview) to a new table.

Comment: I think you probably need to create a new `TreeItem` wrapping the same data.

Comment: That's what I do now,but the problem is setting the graphic back to null on the treecell in the original treeview if the user decides to remove it from the new one. That's why I thought of a listener checking if the treecell/item exists on boths treeviews.

Comment: Let me further explain what I do now: I have one treeview for each connected table. Each treeitem represents a column, If the user adds the item to the new treeview, I add that column to the new table, and the treeitem in the original treeview gets a green V as the graphic. If the user deletes the newly added treeitem the original treeeitem in the original treeview should loose the green V. I've a hard time removing the V, that's why I thought it would be better to do with a listener.

Comment: I removed the whole treeview approach :-)